# Continous deployment and reconfiguring builds in Git

Tags: git, github, entity-framework-core

I generally run my development code in EntityFramework development configration without migrations enabled so I can mod the database as needed without constanly re-running Add-Migration. My deployment to live typically consists of the following steps:

1. Copy entire app to new "Deployment" repository
2. Remove `Database.EnsureDeleted()` and `Database.EnsureCreated()` from program.cs, replace with `Database.Mirgate()`.
3. Restore EFCore Migration folder, which has been deleted when I do step 1.
4. Run Add-Migration to pick up changes;
5. Save change to the EFCore Migration back to Deployment repository;
6. Send code live;

My problem is that when I go live I generally need to restore previous migrations, add a new one and then re-save the new set ready for the next one. What I don't know how to do is to store just the changes which convert code from development to deployable and then overlay that on to the new version.

How can I do this in GitHub? Ideally I would like the following:

- All code in main Development branch set
- On deploy, merge Dev branch into a Preparation branch
- Overlay the changes I need to make from a LiveConfig branch
- Add migrations etc
- Write changes back to the LiveConfig branch (only the changes)
- Merge deployment code to ContinousDeployent Test branch
- merge Test branch to ContinousDeployment Live branch

I'd like to get this working in a single repository but an having trouble working out how to manage the branch which contains the changes I need to make. Any ideas how I can do this?